# Focusing on a Text Field and Removing Focus Based on Checked State

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I have checkbutton;when a user checks it, I need to enable two textboxes ,set focus on the first text box and make it editable.
So far enabling textboxes and setting the focus works.But on unchecking the check button the focus is not removed and the first text box remains editable.

```
if(check_button.state==NSOnState)
        {
        txtone.isEditable=true
        txttwo.isEditable=true
        txtone.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
        else
        {
            txtone.resignFirstResponder()
            txtone.isSelectable=false
            txtone.isEditable =false
            txttwo.isEditable=false

        }
```

What I'm I doing wrong?

Comment: @RashwanL The check action is triggered correctly and the 2 textboxes becomes editable and non editable based on check action.But its after I added `becomefirstresponder` , the issue appeared with the first textbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You´re coding for OSX, so try this instead to remove the focus on a `NSTextField`:

```
txtone.window?.makeFirstResponder(nil)
```

Comment: Awesome! This fixed my issue.Thanks

Comment: @techno, great! Glad to help.